# PHP echoing on same lines in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I currently have a function that is pulling user tickets from my database. It is pulling that data correctly but for some reason instead of echoing the ticket numbers on two separate lines it is placing them in the first row of the table. Can anybody help me figure out why this would be happening?

[image]

This is the function:

```
function findUserTickets() {
    include_once("dbh.php");
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE uid=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
        echo "Ticket #".$row['tid'];
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    include("includes/functions.inc.php");
    include_once("includes/dbh.php");
    $userID = $_SESSION['id'];
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE uid='$userID'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $strSQL);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    ?>
        <li>
            <div class="hk_sug_domian_name">
                <p>
                    <?php echo findUserTickets(); ?>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="hk_domain_price">
                <span class="active_price"><?php echo checkTicketStatus(); ?>  </span>
                <div class="hk_promot_btn"><a class="hk_btn" href="progress.php">View</a></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php 
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is echoing on the same line, because in your loop you have `echo "Ticket #".$row['tid'];` without any line breaks.

Comment: Also, your code makes no sense. Why are you doing a function, where you select the same table/data, inside a loop where you are selecting the same table/data? There are multiple redundancies here.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of calling of function directly you can use $row**

change from

```
<div class="hk_sug_domian_name">
        <p>
            <?php echo findUserTickets(); ?>
        </p>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="hk_sug_domian_name">
        <p>
            <?php echo "Ticket #".$row['tid']; ?>
        </p>
</div>
```